# Grabbing taxonomy terms and inserting them into an array

Tags: wp-query, terms

I am using the shortcake UI plugin and working towards registering a series of shortcodes into the UI interface.

I am trying to grab all the taxonomy terms (via get_terms()) and then populating arrays for the interface. Right now I am getting a parse error as such:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in...
```

here is the code:

```
// Register the Featured Pages shortcode with 'Shortcake UI' plugin
add_action( 'register_shortcode_ui', 'shortcode_ui_feat_pages' );

function shortcode_ui_feat_pages()
{
    shortcode_ui_register_for_shortcode(
        'featured-pages',
        array(
            'label' => 'Featured Pages Shortcode',
            'listItemImage' => 'dashicons-editor-table',
            'attrs' => array(
                array(
                    'label' => 'Category',
                    'attr' => 'category',
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'options' => array(
                    $feat_pages_terms = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => 'featured_page_category', 'hide_empty' => false));
                    foreach($feat_pages_terms as $feat_page_term) :
                        echo 'array(\'value\' =>\'' . $feat_page_term->name . '\', \'label\' =>\'' . $feat_page_term->name . '\'), ';
                    endforeach;
                    ),
                    'description' => 'Insert the category full name (i.e. Home page)',
                ),
                array(
                    'label' => 'Columns',
                    'attr' => 'cols',
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'options' => array(
                        array('value' => '', 'label' => esc_html__('')),
                        array('value' => 2, 'label' => esc_html__('Two')),
                        array('value' => 3, 'label' => esc_html__('Three')),
                        array('value' => 4, 'label' => esc_html__('Four')),
                    ),
                    'description' => 'The number of columns you want to display within a row',
                ),
                array(
                    'label' => 'Order By',
                    'attr' => 'orderby',
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'options' => array(
                        array('value' => '', 'label' => esc_html__('None')),
                        array('value' => 'ID', 'label' => esc_html__('ID')),
                        array('value' => 'author', 'label' => esc_html__('Author')),
                        array('value' => 'title', 'label' => esc_html__('Title')),
                        array('value' => 'name', 'label' => esc_html__('Name')),
                        array('value' => 'date', 'label' => esc_html__('Date')),
                        array('value' => 'modified', 'label' => esc_html__('Modified')),
                        array('value' => 'rand', 'label' => esc_html__('Random')),
                        array('value' => 'menu_order', 'label' => esc_html__('Menu order')),
                    ),
                    'description' => 'Choose how you want to order the Featured Pages',
                ),
                array(
                    'label' => 'Order',
                    'attr' => 'order',
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'options' => array(
                        array('value' => '', 'label' => esc_html__('')),
                        array('value' => 'ASC', 'label' => esc_html__('Ascending')),
                        array('value' => 'DESC', 'label' => esc_html__('Descending')),
                    ),
                    'description' => 'You can order the pages in ascending or descending order (A-Z or Z-A)',
                )
            ),
        )
    );
}
```

I have tested the foreach loop outside the code which registers the featured-pages array and it outputs fine. I'm just a bit stuck getting it to populate the options for select from the custom post type taxonomy 'featured_page_category'.

It just doesn't like me declaration to get_terms() when making the variable $feat_pages_terms.

Do I have to run this logic outside the shortcode ui registration and explode the values into it later?

Comment: you can't have lines of code inside an array!

Comment: Oh ok, Could you possible suggest how I can get the values I need looped and printed into an array?

Comment: You are confusing this with php creating html, you are not creating the code using strings here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates the multidimensional array in advance and then assigns it to options. The multidimensional array is created by assigning an array to each element of the main array. I have reused the $feat_pages_terms variable, but you can also create a separate variable using array() and assign array elements to that, I am including those lines as commented lines. When using this option, $key is not needed as new elements are simply being appended.

```
function shortcode_ui_feat_pages()
{
    $feat_pages_terms = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => 'featured_page_category', 'hide_empty' => false));
    //$multiarr = array();
    foreach($feat_pages_terms as $key => $feat_page_term) :
        $feat_pages_terms[$key] = array('value' => $feat_page_term->name, 'label' => $feat_page_term->name);
        //$multiarr[] = array('value' => $feat_page_term->name, 'label' => $feat_page_term->name);
    endforeach;
    shortcode_ui_register_for_shortcode(
        'featured-pages',
        array(
            'label' => 'Featured Pages Shortcode',
            'listItemImage' => 'dashicons-editor-table',
            'attrs' => array(
                array(
                    'label' => 'Category',
                    'attr' => 'category',
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'options' =>$feat_pages_terms/*$multiarr*/,
                    'description' => 'Insert the category full name (i.e. Home page)',
                ),
...
```

Comment: You sir, are my hero. Thank you so much. It appears so obvious to me now

Comment: you're welcome :) not a sir, though ;)

Comment: he he, gotcha ;)